# manhattan distances

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the most optimal way of calculating [manhattan distances](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance)

My current solution is:

```
def distance(state):
    target_state = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0)
    target_matrix = np.reshape(np.asarray(list(target_state)),(-1,3))
    reshaped_matrix = np.reshape(np.asarray(list(state)),(-1,3))
    dist = 0
    for i in range(1,9):
        dist = dist + (abs(np.where(target_matrix == i)[0][0]
                           - np.where(reshaped_matrix == i)[0][0]) +
                       abs(np.where(target_matrix == i)[1][0]
                           - np.where(reshaped_matrix == i)[1][0]))

    return dist
```

Comment: There must be something you are not explaining to us. The manhattan distance is `dx + dy`, which is a plenty efficient way of calculating it as well.

Comment: The target state remains the same. Is there a better way of doing than my way ?

Comment: I would definitely not use numpy for this...

Comment: what is a better way then ?

Comment: Use vanilla Python lists.

Comment: I think you need to describe what your states are better. I'm guessing from a partial understanding of your code that they're for a sliding tile game? Without that information I'd naturally assume a tuple state to be a vector, rather than an description of tile positions. Finding the manhattan distance between two vectors is fairly trivial in numpy: `np.abs(np.asarray(target_state) - np.asarray(state)).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
import numpy as np

def summed_manhattan(state):
    shuffle = np.reshape((np.array(state)-1) % 9, (3, 3))
    all_dists = np.abs(np.unravel_index(shuffle, (3, 3)) - np.indices((3, 3)))
    all_dists.shape = 2, 9
    gap = np.where(shuffle.ravel() == 8)[0][0]
    return all_dists[:, :gap].sum() + all_dists[:, gap + 1 :].sum()
```

This improves your solution by avoiding the repeated calls to where (which tally up to O(n^2)). Instead, taking advantage of the simple structure of target_state, it calculates for each index into state the index into target_state that holds the same value; the permutation is stored in shuffle. This little trick makes the algorithm O(n) and as a bonus makes it easy to vectorise.

This solution is optimal in the sense that one obviously cannot do better than O(n).

Comment: This does not give the same answer for input state. Example state is (2, 8, 3, 1, 0, 5, 4, 7, 6)

Comment: Oops, sorry, will look into it.

Comment: @Harjatin I think I found the culprit (was referencing the gap in the wrong ordering), could you have another look?